# Cannot select specific result in Search using Protractor - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, testing, protractor

I'm trying to select a specific company from a dropdown list for an automated test. I need to be able to select the exact same company each time. The current script I have only selects the 2nd child in the list so if the list is updated or changed, the script breaks so I'd like to find a way to select the exact company I want regardless of where it sits in the list.
This is what Inspect Element in Chrome shows when I look at the company name in the list. The company in this case is Test Master. Site is primarily AngularJS.

```
<span class="company-name ng-binding" bind-html-unsafe="match.model.name.length > 40 ? (match.model.name.substr(0,40) + '...').toLowerCase() : match.model.name.toLowerCase() | typeaheadHighlight:query"><strong>test master</strong></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate it by text:

```
element(by.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'company-name')]/strong[. = 'test master']").click();
```

Or, you can get all of the `span` elements with `company-name` class and [filter](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) the desired one based on the model value:

```
element.all(by.css("span.company-name")).filter(function (company) {
    return company.evaluate("match.model.name").then(function (companyName) {
        return companyName === "test master";
    });
}).first().click();
```

---

You may also need to [wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for the element to become clickable:

```
var company = element(by.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'company-name')]/strong[. = 'test master']");

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(company), 5000);
company.click();
```

Comment: I added it the script and executed and came back with an error:   NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'company-name')]/strong[. = 'test master']")

Comment: I tried the first solution and got an error: Uncaught exception: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window" The second kept timing out so I changed the timeout value and still no luck. If you have time, you can go to the site directly and do a search so you can see exactly what I'm looking at. www.openbookben.com